# Swagger BaseURL empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using the following Nuget in my ASP.NET Web API: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/ Version: 5.6.0

I see the base URL on the Swagger for my API, shows blank. Is there a way to add base URL or remove that tag entirely?

[Click here to see the image of the base URL on the swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxW4o.png)

I installed the Nuget package & updated the generated SwaggerConfig.cs as follows:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "API title").Contact(cc => cc.Name("team name").Email("email address"));
            c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\xmlName.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
        })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentTitle("document title");
            c.DisableValidator();
            c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
        });
```

Comment: Where's your code? How are you configuring Swagger?

Comment: @Andy I updated the post with code in SwaggerConfig.cs